# Call to undefined function nocache_headers()

Tags: fatal-error

After updating a Wordpress, or merely doing something minor like attempting to deactivate a plugin, the site might get occasionally get stuck in a non-functional state where it merely outputs an error message like the following:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function nocache_headers() in /wp-admin/admin.php

What might be the cause for this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were wp files in the web root which had file size of 0 bytes.

Uploading proper copies from the zip file resolved the problem.

The same cause of the problem has occurred to me quite a few times in the past, but I had forgotten it.

Comment: please describe more about this wp file that i cant found that in zip file

Comment: They were just wp-* files found in the web root.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_multisite() in /home/baseline/public_html/wp-includes/default-constants.php on line 20

Comment: Some (buggy) plugins might fail when attempting to update wp-config.php, causing it to become an empty file. In my case the plugin gave a completely unrelated error, making it far from obvious to realize it had destroyed the config file.

Comment: you saved my day; the file wp-load.php was blank.